# Vuex 3 TypeError: Vue.mixin is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Using client-side only installation.

```
<script src="lib/vue3.2.2.global.js"></script>
<script src="lib/vuex3.6.2.js"></script>
```

I try Vue with mixins

```
app.mixin({
  created() {
    const myOption = this.$options.myOption
    if (myOption) {
      console.log(myOption)
    }
  }
})
x = app.mount("#app")
```

and it works just fine

Then I try usual example from Vuex manual (withous Use or Import, of course)

```
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

And it comes with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Vue.mixin is not a function
    at applyMixin (vuex3.6.2.js:16)
    at install (vuex3.6.2.js:932)
    at new Store (vuex3.6.2.js:382)
    at learnvue.htm:59
```

P.S. also tried import 'Vuex' from Vuex to make sure it's not a module version.

Comment: Vuex 3 is for Vue 2

Comment: Thanks, I was mislead by if (version >= 2) {  Vue.mixin({ beforeCreate: vuexInit });}